# Increase Servers folder depth limit for running scripts?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, webserver, cpanel, configuration

I have a CMS on my site that utilises TinyMCE (the WYSIWYG text editor). The issue is that TinyMCE cannot browse for files (example: images) on the web server. I get the error:

`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`

I have been told this may be occurring because the server is configured to limit the folder depth for running scripts.

Unfortunately I am primarily a front end developer so I am not really sure how to go about changing/viewing this.

I have access to WHM and cPanel. Does anyone know how to adjust this?

Comment: Must admit, I have not heard of such a "folder depth limit", other than that imposed by the OS (that doesn't mean there isn't one). What OS and webserver are you using? If there is such a limit then I imagine this will be outside the realm of WHM and cPanel - just a hunch.

Answer (score 1):

I too had problems with cPanel/TinyMCE integration when it came to handling files. I had to bump up the following to allow larger files to be uploaded through TinyMCE using the images plugin (I believe all of these are in *php.ini* or accessible through WHM's UI):

- `max_execution_time`
- `max_input_time`
- `memory_limit`
- `post_max_size`
- `upload_max_filesize`

Also, make sure the folder you're trying to upload images to is set to 755 (or whatever permission you need, personally, as long as owner can write).

**But, in particular, this sounds like a browser issue:** Are you using Google Chrome? It seems to be the common culprit related to this problem, according to the Interwebs. Try Firefox or Safari- the issue may not be your code/server after all.

Comment: Ah thanks - Yeah I dont think its a browser issue. Firefox gives me the error: 'The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading'. Safari just gives a blank page. I've tried to modify those in htaccess to no available.

Answer (score 1):

I found good site which was helpful to solve the error:

`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`

You can browse this site if you want  to know more about it..

- http://www.z-car.com/blog/web/google-chromes-new-false-start-feature?doing_wp_cron=1358522209.7925169467926025390625

I went to browser shortcut and changed target properties to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --use-system-ssl`.

...adding `--use system-ssl` on the end and it worked.

On an XP computer: `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --disable-ssl-false-start --flag-switches-end`.

...just adding `--flag-switches-begin --disable-ssl-false-start --flag-switches-end`.